# Serializable Boost library header and header-only libraries

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, serialization, boost

I'm building a program that uses the following Boost headers (I'm using Microsoft Visual C++ 10),

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/info_parser.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
```

Now apparently the program only needs library binaries for `date_time`, `filesystem`, `regex`, `system` and `thread`.

However, I am getting a link error looking for the serialization library.

> LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_serialization-vc100-mt-gd-1_44.lib'

I have two questions:

1. What header file above requires the serialization library?
2. Where can I find a list of headers that require binary libraries (along with which library they are associated with) and which ones are header-only? I have looked for quite a while and can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It's possible that either `Boost.PropertyTree` or `Boost.DateTime` are asking for the `libboost_serialization`. Both [Boost.PropertyTree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/property_tree/reference.html#header.boost.property_tree.ptree_serialization_hpp) and [Boost.DateTime](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/date_time/serialization.html) libraries support integration with `Boost.Serialization`, so one of them could be requiring that the serialization library be linked. My money's on `Boost.PropertyTree`, because the above link for date/time specifies that you must explicitly include the serialization headers to get support for it, so it's unlikely that `Boost.DateTime` would need the serialization library unless you include those files.
2. Here's a list of those Boost libraries which [support automatic linking](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/?view=filtered_autolink), so they require linking to library files. Here is the list of [header-only libraries](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/?view=filtered_header-only). I'm not sure if the union of both sets forms the whole boost library, but it seems pretty complete.